# Changed Report to Portrait, but design view is still Landscape

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc

I am working on a Microsoft Report and have found it too long to fit on the page. In the time-honoured way I have fixed this problem by changing the report to Portrait. So far, so good.

But having done so, I need to rearrange things a little, but the Design View in Visual Studio shows the report in Landscape still. This makes arranging anything guesswork. How do I get the design view to display the report in portrait?

I have tried setting the orientation by using the report properties, and also by specifying the dimensions. I have tried restarting Visual Studio, and restarting Visual Studio after deleting the .suo file. But the design view remains the same.

Comment: Have you tried just to drag the report border to the portrait dimension (21cm)? Maybe there are some controls on the report that doesn't let you resize the report with.

Comment: @Raphael, yes, that was the case, thank you. It all seems a bit second-rate, though. A WYSIWYG display that doesn't actually show what you are going to get...